# iOS static const array loaded from plist

Tags: ios, arrays, plist

I have an array that contains RGB values which I have defined as:

```
static const RGB rgbValues[] =
{

    { 255, 0,    0   },
    { 223, 123,  213 },
    { 255, 10,   23  },
    { 255, 230,  100 },
};
```

However I want to load values from a plist instead. I know how to read from a plist and extract values however naturally I can't place that code into the static const array declaration.

Could anyone suggest where/how I would do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You want to read about initializer methods.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the format of your plist is hard to provide a precise answer, anyway you want to use `NSArray` and its `initWithContentsOfFile:` initializer. Something like

```
NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rgb"
                                                      ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray * rgbArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```